# What thread runs the code after the `await` keyword?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

Let me just post a simple example:

```
    private void MyMethod()
    {
        Task task = MyAsyncMethod();
        task.Wait();
    }

    private async Task MyAsyncMethod()
    {
        //Code before await
        await MyOtherAsyncMethod();
        //Code after await
    }
```

Let's say I run the above code in a single threaded app -like a console app-. I'm having a difficult time understanding how the code `//Code after await` would be able to run.


I understand that when I hit the `await` keyword in `MyAsyncMethod()` control goes back to `MyMethod()`, but then I'm locking the thread with `task.Wait()`. If the thread is locked, how can `//Code after await` ever run if the thread that is supposed to take it is locked?


Does a new thread get created to run `//Code after await`? Or does the main thread magically steps out of `task.Wait()` to run `//Code after await`?


I'm not sure how this is supposed to work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Code as posted will "Deadlock" in Winform App if called from main thread because you're blocking the main thread with the `Wait()`.

> But in console app this works. but how?

Answer is hidden in the `SynchronizationContext.Current`. `await` captures the "SynchronizationContext" and when the task is completed it will continue in the same "SynchronizationContext".

In winform app `SynchronizationContext.Current` will be set to `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` which will post to the call to "Message loop", but who is going to process that? out main thread is waiting in `Wait()`.

In console app `SynchronizationContext.Current` will not be set by default so it will be `null` when no "SynchronizationContext" available for await to capture so it will schedule the continuation to `ThreadPool`(TaskScheduler.Default which is ThreadpoolTaskScheduler) and so the code after await works(through threadpool thread).

Aforementioned capturing behavior can be controlled using `Task.ConfigureAwait(false);` which will prevent winform app from deadlocking but code after `await` no longer runs in UI thread.

Comment: This all assumes that the current synchronization context is never altered by user code; you can set it in any of those applications to whatever you want, and give it whatever behavior you want.

Comment: I had no idea about thread pools behind .Net console apps. Being aware of that now answers everything. Thank you.

Comment: @YasmaniLlanes If you don't have idea about "ThreadPool" I'd suggest you to read about it. It should be this way learn ThreadPool first then TPL and then async/await.

Comment: so after ``await`` keyword,on next line whatever code is, will be executed in the calling thread means UI thread ?

Comment: How can this deadlock? Doesn't it just freeze until task.Wait() finishes?

Comment: @user764754 I'm too lazy at the moment. I'll share you a blog post which explains why it deadlocks. Refer http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: *"so it will schedule the continuation to `ThreadPool`"* -- That's not how it works. In the absence of a synchronization context, the continuation runs on whatever thread completed the task ([demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/H6OGCC)). It just happens that all built-in asynchronous APIs in .NET complete their tasks on `ThreadPool` threads, creating this common illusion.

Answer (score 16):

> Does a new thread get created to run //Code after await?

Maybe. Maybe not. The awaitable pattern implementation for `Task` runs the continuation (the bit after the `await` expression) using the synchronization context which was "current" when at the start of the await expression. If you're in the context of a UI thread, for example, that means that you'll end up back on the same UI thread. If you're in a thread-pool thread, you'll *usually* end up back on *some* thread-pool thread in my experience, but it could be a different one - but even that's not certain.

Of course with your code sample, if you're in a UI thread, your call to `Wait()` will block the UI thread so that the continuation *can't* run - you need to be careful about that. (Calling `Wait()` or `Result` on tasks that you don't know to be completed, and which may require work on the current thread, is a bad idea.)

Note that you can call [`Task.ConfigureAwait`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait.aspx) so that you can express the intention of *not* requiring to continue on the same context. This is usually appropriate for library methods which don't care which thread they run on:

```
await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
```

(It affects more than the thread - it's the whole context which is captured or not.)

I think it's a good idea to get familiar with what's going on under the hood with await. There's plenty of documentation online, and if you'll allow me a brief plug, there's also the [3rd edition of C# in Depth](http://manning.com/skeet3), and my [Tekpub screencast series on the topic](http://tekpub.com/products/async). Or start with [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx) and proceed from there.

Comment: Alright, I understand the behavior in the context of a UI thread like in a WCF app or thread pool like in a web app? What happens in a single threaded app like a console app?

Comment: @Jon: The continuation is actually queued to the current `SynchronizationContext`, falling back on the current `TaskScheduler`. This is because `TaskScheduler.Current` is all quirky and not very intuitive.

Comment: @YasmaniLlanes: There's actually no such thing as a single-threaded .NET app; every .NET app has the thread pool. So in this case (when there's no current `SynchronizationContext` or `TaskScheduler`), the continuation is queued to the thread pool.

Comment: @Stephen Cleary You have just answered so many questions with those 3 sentences. I had no idea about the thread pool behind a console app in .Net. With a thread pool plugged into the equation, now everything makes perfect sense. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @StephenCleary: Thanks - have edited to specify the synchronization context instead of task scheduler.

Comment: @Servy: There *is* only one thread pool (at least from the public side of things). It will still be "a thread from the thread pool" but it may be a different thread.

Answer (score 0):

> Let's say I run the above code in a single threaded app -like a console app-.

**Console apps are not single threaded**. The process starts running on one thread, then it may launch an unlimited number of other threads, and finally it terminates when the last [foreground](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.isbackground#remarks) thread exits. *Free-threaded* is probably a more accurate classification for applications of this type.

> What thread runs the code after the `await` keyword?

Since you referred to console apps, I will skip entirely the implications arising from the presence of a [synchronization context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097471/what-does-synchronizationcontext-do). Console apps are not equipped with such a thing. The static property [`SynchronizationContext.Current`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current) is `null`, which greatly simplifies things, and also makes the [`ConfigureAwait`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait) configuration irrelevant. Both `.ConfigureAwait(false)` and `.ConfigureAwait(true)` have the exact same behavior, because there is no synchronization context to be captured at the `await` point.

The thread that runs the code after the `await` depends on the [`IsCompleted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.taskawaiter.iscompleted) property of the awaiter:

1. If the `TaskAwaiter.IsCompleted` is `true`, the thread after the `await` is the same with the thread before the `await`. That's because the continuation after the `await` is not scheduled, and instead it simply runs synchronously. A typical example of an always completed awaitable is the [`Task.CompletedTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.completedtask):

   ```
   await Task.CompletedTask; // After the await, same thread as before
   ```
2. If the `TaskAwaiter.IsCompleted` is `false`, **the thread after the `await` is the thread that completed the awaitable**. This thread is chosen by the implementation of the awaitable, and is not under the control of the caller. Almost all built-in asynchronous APIs are completing on the [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool), so it's easy to come to the (mistaken) conclusion that there is some active mechanism in place that redirects the continuations to the `ThreadPool`. Some examples of APIs that complete indeed on the `ThreadPool` are the [`Task.Delay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay), the [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) and the [`HttpClient.GetStringAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getstringasync). A rare counterexample is the [`Task.Factory.StartNew`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew) configured with the [`TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions) option. This API invokes the supplied `action` on a newly created background thread, not on a `ThreadPool` thread, and completes the `Task` on that same thread. Here is a demonstration of this behavior:

   ```
   await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Thread.Sleep(100), CancellationToken.None,
       TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);

   Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread); // Prints false
   ```

Conducting such experiments requires some awareness. It is important to ensure that the `await` will complete asynchronously, and that's the reason for the `Thread.Sleep(100)` inside the `action`. If we don't do any work inside the `action`, the `await` might continue synchronously because the `TaskAwaiter.IsCompleted` will be found to be `true`. In which case the [`Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.isthreadpoolthread) will also be `false`, but for the wrong reason: it will be `false` because we'll be still on the main thread of the console application. You can find a more sophisticated demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/H6OGCC), that proves beyond any doubt that the `await` continuations run on the completing thread of the awaited task.

In case you are wondering how you could create yourself an asynchronous method that doesn't complete on the `ThreadPool`, here is a minimal example:

```
Task ExecuteAsync()
{
    TaskCompletionSource tcs = new();
    new Thread(() => { Thread.Sleep(100); tcs.SetResult(); }).Start();
    return tcs.Task;
}
```