# Deadlock for GUI task.wait vs Console or ThreadPool

Tags: c#, task

I'm currently reading through C# in depth(3rd ed) and one of the warnings given is that using a GUI thread with a task.wait is dangerous as it may lead to deadlock. But its not a problem with ThreadPool or Console. My question is why does the thread that is running the task.wait not deadlock so for the following code (taken from book) even a console app (backround) thread would not make it to the catch as it would deadlock.

```
public static void Main(string[] args = null)
{
        var source = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var task = TestInt(source.Token);
        source.CancelAfter(4000);
        Console.WriteLine("Status {0}",task.Status);
        try
        {
            task.Wait();
        }
        catch (AggregateException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Caught {0}",e.InnerExceptions[0]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Final Status: {0}",task.Status);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static async Task TestInt(CancellationToken token, double start = 1)
    {

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), token);
    }
```

Thanks You

Comment: I've explained it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19543729/2530848)

Answer (score 6):

I explain this in detail [in a blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

What happens is that (by default) `await` will capture a current "context" and use that context to resume execution of the `async` method. This "context" is `SynchronizationContext.Current` unless it is `null`, in which case it is `TaskScheduler.Current`.

In your example, `SynchronizationContext.Current` is `null` and `TaskScheduler.Current` is `TaskScheduler.Default`, that is, the thread pool task scheduler. Thus, the `async` method is resumed on a thread pool thread and there is no deadlock. The thread pool thread finishes the `async` method, completing the `Task`, allowing the main thread to finish its wait.

(In the deadlock case, there's a `SynchronizationContext` representing the UI thread, so the `async` method tries to resume on the UI thread but the UI thread is blocked by calling `Wait`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the link to your blog, which seems to have a great amount of threading and synchronization posts.