# ASP.NET Core 2.x google authentication get id_token

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, google-oauth

I'm using Google authentication for my asp.net mvc application.
I added Google to my Startup.cs class:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
{
    googleOptions.ClientId = _configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
    googleOptions.ClientSecret = _configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
    googleOptions.SaveTokens = true;
});
```

I can get access_token from controller using this:

```
var token = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token").ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I need id_token to authenticate to my custom backend application like [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth).
I tried using this code but I get null.

```
var token = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("id_token").ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Is it possible to get id_token somehow?

Comment: did you check if the id_token is sent by google ?

Comment: BTW, [you don't need to use `.ConfigureAwait(false)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42053135)

Answer (score 0):

By default, [Google authentication implementation uses `response_type=code`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google/GoogleHandler.cs#L56). With this flow, you don't have `id_token` in response. To have it, `response_type` should be `response_type=code id_token` (from [here](https://medium.com/@darutk/diagrams-of-all-the-openid-connect-flows-6968e3990660)).

You may override that `BuildChallengeUrl` method in derived `YourGoogleHandler` class, and change DI registration from `.AddGoogle()` to

```
.AddOAuth<GoogleOptions, YourGoogleHandler>
  (GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, GoogleDefaults.DisplayName, googleOptions)
```

(code was taken from [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google/GoogleExtensions.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google/GoogleExtensions.cs)

Comment: I tried your solution but i was getting an error from google that nonce was missing so added this: `queryStrings.Add("nonce", Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));` .
Now i'm getting an exception: `Exception: The oauth state was missing or invalid.`

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me..

```
 services.AddAuthentication()
           .AddOpenIdConnect(GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
               GoogleDefaults.DisplayName,
               options =>
               {
                   options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                   options.Authority =  "https://accounts.google.com";
                   options.ClientId = googleOAuthSettings.ClientId;
                   options.ClientSecret = googleOAuthSettings.ClientSecret;
                   options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
                   options.CallbackPath =  "signin-google";
                   options.SaveTokens = true; //this has to be true to get the token value
                   options.Scope.Add("email");
               });
```

OpenIdConnect provider for Google OAuth allow us to customise the ResponseType.

As per the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56565997/identity-server-4-getschemesupportssignoutasync-returns-incorrect-response?answertab=active#tab-top) , OpenIdConnectHandler which appears to implement IAuthenticationSignOutHandler. So that's why regardless of what is in the discovery document (end session endpoint supported or not), if you use the AddOpenIdConnect(...), it will always register a handler which seemingly supports sign out. If you are using any IdentityServer4 quick start, then you can get rid of that error by checking with a condition in AccountService.cs --> BuildLoggedOutViewModelAsync method.

> var providerSupportsSignOut = await
>   _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetSchemeSupportsSignOutAsync(idp)

Here, we can add additional check like : `idp != Google.`