# Identity Server 4 GetSchemeSupportsSignOutAsync returns incorrect response

Tags: identityserver4

I've setup an open id connect provider, Google in this case, using the AddOpenIdConnect extension method in dotnet core. From the discovery document:

```
https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

it does not seem that google supports federated sign-out because there is no end_session endpoint. However, in Identity Server 4, the call:

```
var providerSupportsSignout = await HttpContext.GetSchemeSupportsSignOutAsync(idp);
```

returns true. So during Logout it tries to sign out of google using:

```
return SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = url }, vm.ExternalAuthenticationScheme);
```

which throws an exception:

```
InvalidOperationException: Cannot redirect to the end session endpoint, the configuration may be missing or invalid.
```

Is this a bug in Identity Server 4 or is there a configuration property that needs to be set when setting up the Oidc provider so that this extension method will pickup that the provider does not support signout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't appear to be a bug in Identity Server 4. The [code](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/41767960bb54cc251ce73e904d1d4d30bd057307/src/IdentityServer4/src/Extensions/HttpContextExtensions.cs#L22) behind this extension calls out to get the underlying authentication scheme handler.

```
    public static async Task<bool> GetSchemeSupportsSignOutAsync(this HttpContext context, string scheme)
    {
        var provider = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IAuthenticationHandlerProvider>();
        var handler = await provider.GetHandlerAsync(context, scheme);
        return (handler != null && handler is IAuthenticationSignOutHandler);
    }
```

In this case, your handler will be `OpenIdConnectHandler` which appears to implement `IAuthenticationSignOutHandler` so that's why regardless of what is in the discovery document (end session endpoint supported or not), if you use the `AddOpenIdConnect(...)`, it will always register a handler which seemingly supports sign out, but as you have pointed out, does not actually enforce the actual idp validation for that kind of functionality support ([link to handler source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Security/Authentication/OpenIdConnect/src/OpenIdConnectHandler.cs)).

And lastly, worthwhile to mention, that Identity Server 4 check is rightful here as according to [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.iauthenticationsignouthandler?view=aspnetcore-2.2), the `IAuthenticationSignOutHandler` is indeed basically a marker interface used to determine if a handler supports SignOut.

So I guess you just simply can't use the generic `AddOpenIdConnect(...)`, instead perhaps you should use `AddGoogle(...)` which does not implement `IAuthenticationSignOutHandler` so will work as expected with Identity Server 4 ([link to source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Security/Authentication/Google/src/GoogleHandler.cs#L19)).

Answer (score 0):

As Vidmantas Blazevicius mentioned, using .AddOpenIdConnect will make the extension method default to true because of the interface. I have changed my code to explicity check for the support of an end_session_endpoint by doing:

```
  var discoveryClient = new IdentityModel.Client.DiscoveryClient("https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration")
                    {
                        Policy = new IdentityModel.Client.DiscoveryPolicy
                        {
                            ValidateEndpoints = false, //this is needed for google, if set to true then will result in error response
                            ValidateIssuerName = false //this is needed for Microsoft, if set to true then will result in error response
                        }
                    };

                    var discoveryResult = await discoveryClient.GetAsync();
                    if (!discoveryResult.IsError)
                    {
                        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(discoveryResult.EndSessionEndpoint))
                            supportsFederatedSignOut = true;

                    }
```

I then save an additional property on the model "SupportsFederatedSignOut" and then use this to determine whether external identity provider signout (SignOut) should be called.