# .NET Core 2.1, Manjuro Linux fails without ConfigureAwait(false)

Tags: async-await, .net-core, synchronizationcontext

I am looking for working theories, because I am clueless.
To my knowledge in .NET Core, `ConfigureAwait(false)` is [not relevant.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42058544/2061103) However I have a code block that stucks on Manjuro Linux if I don't use `ConfigureAwait(false)`. It doesn't stuck on Ubuntu, nor on Windows.

### Environment

`dotnet --version` gives `2.1.401`
FYI: Manjuro Linux is Arch Linux based (so it'd likely fail on Arch, too).

### Context

Relevant codeblock on GitHub: https://github.com/zkSNACKs/WalletWasabi/pull/636/files#r213737187

`await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false);`

I call this delay before I start an external process and then, after the delay, another awaited async function tries to establish connection to this process (through SOCKS5) to check if it was started properly: `if (!await IsTorRunningAsync(TorSocks5EndPoint))`.

Finally I call this function from an xUnit test with `dotnet test`.

### Question

Any theory on why would such a thing happen?

Comment: I can't say why it happens specifically in this case, but it's important to note that the *not relevant* statement applies only to ASP.NET Core (the framework) rather than .NET Core (the runtime). It's perfectly possible for something targetting .NET Core to have a `SynchronizationContext`.

Comment: To add to Kirk's point, you can check the current SynchronizationContext using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_SynchronizationContext_Current 
If you don't need the current thread freed before delay, just use `Thread.Sleep`

Comment: Thanks, for the record it does work with `Thread.Sleep`, too.

Answer (score 0):

As you know perhaps `Configure(await)` in NetFramework saying do not use information from Synchonization Context, so if this context doesn't exists in .NET Core - of course this function do nothing.

Unfortunately your code in github has changed so it is not clear what the question is. So my advise is - please read this [explanation](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html) from Stephen Cleary.