# .Net core & SynchronizationContext & Thread.SetData

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, synchronizationcontext

From what I know, AspNetCore [*doesn't have*](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html) `SynchronizationContext` .

> That “re-entering” the request context involves a number of
>   housekeeping tasks, such as setting HttpContext.Current and the
>   current thread’s identity and culture.

So I've created a simple .Net Core Api project with an action:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("checkVar")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> checkVar()
    {
        Thread.SetData(Thread.GetNamedDataSlot("Random"),4);
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        var res = Thread.GetData(Thread.GetNamedDataSlot("Random"));
    }
```

To my suruprise , `res` had a value of `4`. I was surprised because I believe that `SetData` was part of the synchronization context. (which should not exist in asp.net core)

More, when I used `ConfigureAwait(false)` , I got `null` in `res`.

So now I'm confused. Because `ConfigureAwait` [shouldn't have effect in asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42053135/configureawaitfalse-relevant-in-asp-net-core)

**Question:**

If asp.net core doesn't have a SynchronizationContext, then why did `4` was available after `await` ? why does the `ConfigureAwait` change the result in a non-SynchronizationContext environment?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> I was surprised because I believe that SetData was part of the synchronization context. (which should not exist in asp.net core)

No; `SetData` is thread-local storage (TLS). So it's tied to a specific thread. This doesn't have anything to do with synchronization contexts.

> More, when I used ConfigureAwait(false) , I got null in res.

Depending on when you run this code, how busy the server is, etc., you could get `null` or `4` with or without `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

> If asp.net core doesn't have a SynchronizationContext, then why did 4 was available after await ?

It's a thread-specific value. There's no `SynchronizationContext` on ASP.NET Core, and your code will resume on any available thread pool thread. If that thread *happens* to be the same thread that started that method, then the TLS is going to still be there because it's for that specific thread.

The same behavior actually applies to ASP.NET pre-Core. In that case, there is a `SynchronizationContext`, but that context isn't tied to any particular thread. Just like ASP.NET Core, asynchronous methods on ASP.NET pre-Core can resume on any available thread pool thread, so TLS data may or may not be there after an `await`.

To support this theory with data, try logging `Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId` before and after the `await` and see if there's any correlation between the data being present and the id remaining the same.

Comment: Isn't synchronization context contains culturinfo data etc? That's is the reason why ithought it also contains tls

Comment: @RoyiNamir: The ASP.NET (pre-Core) SyncCtx includes the culture for the current request/page. That's the only SyncCtx that ever included that; none of the others do. In *addition* to the culture in the ASP.NET (pre-Core) SyncCtx, each thread *also* has its own culture and "UI culture".

Comment: @StephenCleary Hi Stephen, Thanks for the great Article. So when the async operation is completed and next line of code is getting executed, how does the request details like cookie/query string are preserved ?
I mean without the SynchronizationContext, how does the .net core knows that which was the original thread that should continue the execution once async operation is performed ? 
Because I believe only that thread will have the details of that specific request, or how else the other thread will get the details of that specific request ?

Comment: @JayShah: The old ASP.NET way of doing this was setting they static `HttpContext.Current` property. That property does not exist on ASP.NET Core. With Core, all cookies, query strings, and other request/response-specific data is all local variables, not static variables.

Comment: Hi @StephenCleary, from the comment above, what do you mean by local variables? If the SyncCtx doesn't exist anymore, how's the HttpContext.Current property restored on (if happens) a different thread? Thanks.

Comment: @YuriCardoso: There *is* no `HttpContext.Current` property on ASP.NET Core. Local variables are ones defined in the method, as well as the implicit `this`.

Comment: @StephenCleary. How does ASP NET CORE know to resolve the same instance scoped per http request (or azure function execution) - even in the case where the thread executing the continuation is different from the initial thread.There must be some 'synchronization' mechanism: Quote: "The scoped service lifetime matches a function execution lifetime. Scoped services are created once per execution. Later requests for that service during the execution reuse the existing service instance." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection

Comment: @AdrianNasui: There is an `AsyncLocal<T>` type that provides an async-aware scope. It's roughly equivalent to the old [logical call context](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html). I suspect (but have not verified) that .NET Core DI uses this technique to determine the "current" scope. I do know that .NET Core logging scopes do use this technique.

Answer (score 1):

You're invoking `SetData` on `Thread`. How come you thought it was part of `SynchronizationContext`.

You can easily test if there's a current `SynchronizationContext` by checking the value of `SynchronizationContext.Current`- If it's `null`, then there's no `SynchronizationContext`.

How many concurrent requests did you issued to test that code?

`SynchronizationContext` or not the way the framework/runtime flows the context (like in types like `AsyncLocal<T>`) is through the `ExecutionContext` data, not `Thread` data.

Comment: Isn't synchronization context contains culturinfo data etc? That's is the reason why ithought it also contains tls

Comment: Where did you get that idea? The `SynchronizationContext` is only about synchronizing to a common context.