# Losing [ThreadStatic] value after calling a Task

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, threadstatic

I'm using a variable with `[ThreadStatic]` attribute to store the current active `Session` for each socket (I'm using **WebSocket** as the connection type). In the beginning of socket `connect`, I assign its value with a new `Session` object, and then executing a `Task` method to get an output. After the `Task` is completed, the `Session` value become `null`.

`ThreadStatic` declaration:

```
public class Session
{
    ...
    [ThreadStatic] public static Session _session;
}
```

Task method to call:

```
public async Task<string> Connect()
{
    var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "storyboard", "1.json");
    var json = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(path, Encoding.UTF8);

    return $"\"i\":{this.id},\"m\":\"build\",\"a\":{json}";
}
```

The task execution part:

```
// Session._session == null ? --> false (here, the value still exists)
var res = await obj.Item1.Execute(met, args); // execute a method with async call
await Session._session.Send(res); // Session._session == null ? --> true
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Why do you not just keep it in a local variable in your final code sample? `var session = new Session();` should still have `session` set correctly in the last line.

Comment: It's just an example, I initialize the `Session._session` value in another place somewhere (not locally) and I need to use that in many places.

Comment: That's because there is [no synchronization context](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html) in ASP.NET Core. The continuation resumes on a random thread. Even in ASP.NET non-Core, the approach is [flawed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57263577/11683).

Comment: Is there another way to resolve this limitation?

Answer (score 4):

Tasks and threads are largely unrelated concepts, and importantly: in most interesting scenarios, any time you `await`, you are inherently potentially *changing thread*. Incidentally, that is why you can't have a `lock` that spans an `await`, because the compiler knows that `lock` requires the same thread at both sides.

Because of this, anything that is thread-specific, such as `[ThreadStatic]`, is probably going to be invalid when you get back from the `await` (unless it happens to be a no-op `await` on a synchronous or completed operation, or if there is a sync-context in play that is reliably pushing work back to the same thread).

There is an [`AsyncLocal<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.asynclocal-1) that is probably more suitable for your scenario, and can *largely* be swapped for `ThreadLocal` (with some caveats around directionality), but to be honest it would be *simpler* to just pass the state along explicitly, rather than ambiently.

Comment: Thank you. After reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.asynclocal-1, I think I'll use `AsyncLocal<T>` instead to keep my variable's value `across the threads`.