# Is it necessary to use ConfigureAwait in BusinessLogic and WebApi? or just enough in one?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, configureawait

If I set ConfigureAwait (false) in the logic I also need to specify it in the WebApi? ASP.NET

[My Business Logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74rAJ.png) 
Using ConfigureAwait

[My WebApi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tANfO.png)
Here you also have to set ConfigureAwait?

Comment: In WebApi it is not necessary to `ConfiguareAwait(false)` because there is no `SyncronizationContext` in Webapi and no chance of blocking for that matter.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying my doubt

Comment: you're welcome :)

Comment: @Siavash Source for that claim?

Comment: @KennethK. There are many. but this answer is a concise one. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42058544/4794962

Comment: @Siavash This question is not tagged as [tag:asp.net-core]; your link specifically says that Core does not have a sync context, but a comment says that classic ASP.NET does.

Comment: @KennethK. my mind went straight to .net core but in case of .net framework well then, yes there is context and you can configure to false.