# ConfigureAwait(false) in .Net Core application

Tags: asynchronous, .net-core, async-await, configureawait

I am creating a cron job using .Net Core which will fetch data from API and insert data into database.
Should I use ConfigureAwait(false) while calling api in asynchronous mode?

I am confused after reading article - [ConfigureAwait(false) relevant in ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42053135/configureawaitfalse-relevant-in-asp-net-core)

Since I am having console app  not a UI app so Please suggest Should be go with ConfigureAwait(false) or not

Comment: ASP.NET Core does not have an `AspNetSynchronizationContext` (or any `SynchronizationContext`). As there is no context anymore, `ConfigureAwait(false)` is no longer needed.

Comment: But I read, ConfigureAwait (false) increase performance.I m having .Net core console app which is calling Api asynchronously

Comment: if your API is not synchronized one, you can use ConfigureAwait(false) it will not stop other Tasks being run.

Comment: Api has asynchronous methods so Do I need to use ConfigureAwait(false) or not with Api calls ?

Comment: yes, you can use that.

Answer (score 2):

In short: if you are asking, then you don't need to use ConfigureAwait(false) in your application.

.NET Core framework has no SynchronizationContext. So in this contextless approach from .NET Core, the default asynchronous behavior is the same as we have, when using ConfigureAwait(false), so when an async handler resumes execution, a thread is taken from the thread pool and goes the work.

Source: https://itnext.io/a-deep-dive-into-configureawait-65f52b9605c2