# Debugging a nasty Lock Contention issue in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httpclient, iocp, contention

We are dealing with a nasty lock contention issue in a high traffic ASP.NET Core MVC app in .NET 6, hosted as in-process in IIS Windows Server.

We are trying to enable a feature that makes an Http call to an internal service, and when we enable the feature, we get increased lock contention (from dotnet-counters), spikes of CPU (from 20% to 100%), spikes of RAM (from 4GB to 12GB), increased number of threads in thread pool (from ~60 to ~310) and obviously the app struggles to serve the incoming requests.
The issue appears ONLY in the production environment and unfortunately we haven't been able to reproduce it in any other environment (local, UAT, staging).

We've taken countless dumps and traces to analyze and identify the issue, however all of them point to a general "increased lock contention" issue and the hot path is always this stack trace:

```
ntdll.dll!NtRemoveIoCompletion()             
KERNELBASE.dll!GetQueuedCompletionStatus()           
System.Private.CoreLib.dll!00007ff803838421()            
[Managed to Native Transition]
System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.LowLevelLifoSemaphore.WaitForSignal(int timeoutMs = 0x00004e20)
System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.LowLevelLifoSemaphore.Wait(int timeoutMs, bool spinWait)
System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()
System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Thread.StartCallback()
[Native to Managed Transition]
kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk()
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()
```

Actually we see an enormous increase of threads in the dumps taken before and after, all pointing to IOCP threads that wait for the GetQueuedCompletionStatus() method.

Unfortunately we weren't able to identify the worker threads that spawn the IOCP threads, and we are not aware of any way to associate the IOCP thread to the IOCP port and the relevant worker thread.

We are trying blindly to make changes related to our async implementations, but still no luck.

We have also tried all HttpClient patterns just to make sure we are not missing something obvious:
Long lived static HttpClient
Short lived named HttpClient instances with IHttpClientFactory
Custom pool of long lived HttpClient instances

We 've set the minimum worker and iocp threads to 200 and then to 300 from default, still no luck OR any change in behavior of the app.

Running syncblk does not reveal anything (no synchronous locks are detected), neither any other common methods of identifying locks/contention from dumps or traces.

I would really appreciate any feedback on this, since we've been banging our heads on the wall for more than a month now, thank you! :)

Comment: There is very little we can see without debugging the actual application. Perhaps take a look if you are disposing everything correctly, and whether you are streaming data in, and whether you are using `await` correctly (rather than a blocking `.Result` or `.GetResult()`)

Comment: @Charlieface the specific part of code that gets enabled with the feature flag is checked line by line (we are talking about more or less 200 lines of code), everything gets disposed and all async operations are awaited with await.

Comment: How about you show us the code then? Maybe there's something you missed

Comment: I would if I could, this is a proprietary software and I cannot disclose the source code unfortunately. That is why I am asking for help debugging the issue and not on the code itself. The behavior of increased IOCP threads is really peculiar (never encountered such a behavior before) and also all the common debugging techniques fail to identify the issue.

Comment: The problem here is that you are asking for help while providing less info than you had at  your disposal and was not able to find the source of the issue.

Comment: So what do you want us to do if we can't see the code, how could we possibly help you more than you can do yourself?

Comment: I am basically asking if anyone has previous experience with a similar case, and if anyone can propose a technique or tool for identifying such cases.

Comment: BTW you have mentioned `HttpClient` usage - is there any chance you are using custom `HttpClientHandler`?

Comment: Nope, we use the default SocketHttpHandler that comes with .NET 6

Comment: I doubt anyone is going to be able to help with such little information. All I can think of is: Which exact build number of .NET are you on, is it the latest?

Answer (score 0):

See comment by Palec
[ConfigureAwait(false) relevant in ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42053135/configureawaitfalse-relevant-in-asp-net-core)

> The question is clearly about ASP.NET Core, but I would add that even the app using the framework may theoretically create and configure its own SynchronizationContext, or a weird library may do so. If you are the app's developer, you should know about any such things, and likely, no such craziness is in the app. If you are a library developer, you should use ConfigureAwait even if the library is meant to be used with ASP.NET Core, or document that its use with a synchronization context is not supported.

I think you should give a try to the **ConfigureAwait(false)**... this was a solution many times before.