# Strange deadlock while sync with TaskCompletionSource and AutoResetEvent

Tags: c#, task, deadlock, autoresetevent, taskcompletionsource

While running the following C# program, I randomly got two different results.
Result 1 (occurred frequently) is actually deadlocked. Please explain to me why this happened.
I am not expecting the deadlock while using WaitOne on AutoResetEvent.

```
   class Program
    {
        static async Task Main()
        {
            TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = new();
            AutoResetEvent evtFinished = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            Func<Task> func = async Task () => 
                { await Task.Delay(10); tcs.SetResult(true); evtFinished.Set(); };
            var t = func.Invoke();
            //await func.Invoke();
            await tcs.Task;
            if (evtFinished.WaitOne(1000))
                Console.WriteLine("First Wait OK");
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("First Wait Timeout");
                for (int i = 0; i < 10 && !evtFinished.WaitOne(100); i++)
                    Console.WriteLine($" {i+1} Wait Timeout"); 
                await t;
                evtFinished.WaitOne();
                Console.WriteLine("Wait OK");
            }
        }
    }
```

---

```
<<<<<Result 1: >>>>>>
# First Wait Timeout
#  1 Wait Timeout
#  2 Wait Timeout
#  3 Wait Timeout
#  4 Wait Timeout
#  5 Wait Timeout
#  6 Wait Timeout
#  7 Wait Timeout
#  8 Wait Timeout
#  9 Wait Timeout
#  10 Wait Timeout
# Wait OK
```

---

```
<<<<<Result2 >>>>>
# First Wait OK
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, `TaskCompletionSource.SetResult` runs its `Task` continuations *synchronously* (in most cases).

This means that in your case, everything after `await tcs.Task` and up to the next `await` will run *before* the `evtFinished.Set()` is even reached.

There are multiple way to solve this, but the easiest one will be to pass the `TaskContinuationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously` flag to the `TaskCompletionSource` constructor.

Comment: Thank you very much. the solution works.

Comment: If the solution works, please mark the answer as accepted~

Answer (score 1):

There's a few combining reasons why this is happening. First, the [basic behavior of `await`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) (as described on my blog) is that it captures a "context" and - by default - resumes in that "context". In this case, there is no context, so `async` methods resume on a thread pool thread. Second, when an awaitable completes, if the thread completing the awaitable is compatible with the context captured by the `await`, it will execute that continuation synchronously. More specifically, `await` uses `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously`.

This scenario is explored in more depth in my blog post [don't block in asynchronous code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/dont-block-in-asynchronous-code.html).

So, walking through it:

1. `Main` starts on the main thread and calls `func.Invoke`.
2. `func.Invoke` hits its `await` and returns an incomplete task, stored in `t`.
3. `Main` continues executing (still on the main thread) and does the `await tcs.Task`.
4. Assuming the `tcs` is not yet completed (this is the race condition), then `Main` returns an incomplete task.
5. When the `Task.Delay` completes, a thread pool thread is used to resume executing `func`.
6. This thread pool thread calls `tcs.SetResult`, which now has a continuation attached (the remainder of `Main`).
7. Since the thread pool thread is compatible with the captured context (it's a thread pool thread), it just executes the continuation (the remainder of `Main`) synchronously.
8. This thread then synchronously blocks waiting for `evtFinished` to be set, but it won't be. Note that your call stack is inverted at this point: `func` has actually called the `Main` continuation. You can verify this by making the delay much larger and running in the debugger.
9. Eventually that same thread pool thread will hit `await t`, where it finally yields back to its caller, allowing `func` to finish running, setting `evtFinished`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Explained very well.

Comment: In the top you mention "there is no context", but in step 7 you say "thread pool context". I think this could be made a little bit clearer.

Comment: @SkyNano if answer works for you - do not forget to mark it as accepted one.

Comment: The thread after the `await` is the thread that completed the awaitable. This can be easily proven [experimentaly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543240/what-thread-runs-the-code-after-the-await-keyword/77392646#77392646 "What thread runs the code after the await keyword?"). The default synchronization context is `null`, not the `ThreadPool`.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: Yes; that's what my answer says.

Comment: *"Since the thread pool thread is compatible with the captured context (it's a thread pool thread),"* -- This phrase strongly implies that the origin of the thread is important. In reality no compatibility check is taking place. As long as the captured context is `null`, anything goes. ALL threads are compatible with the `null` context.

Comment: I'd phrase it that there is a compatibility check that takes place, but you are correct that the check always passes when no context is captured.