# What does ConfigureAwait(false) in an async await foreach loop do?

Tags: c#, async-await, iasyncenumerable, configureawait

I am trying to understand the impact of setting `ConfigureAwait(false)` in an `async foreach` loop?

```
await foreach (var item in data.ConfigureAwait(false))
{
  //...
}
```

Exactly where do we lose the synchronization context? When would I want to set `ConfigureAwait(false)` inside the `foreach` look as above?

I understand the point of doing it in the async data source, but what about the `foreach` loop?

I would expect the context inside the loop to have no synchronization context, but my experiments show that the context is still there.

Here's my sample Winform app:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dataSource = new DataFactory();

    IAsyncEnumerable<int> data = dataSource.GetData();

    await foreach (var item in data.ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
        DataFactory.PrintContext("Data - item: " + item);
    }
}

public class DataFactory
{
    public async IAsyncEnumerable<int> GetData()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            await Task.Delay(250).ConfigureAwait(true);
            PrintContext("Generating Data: " + i);
            yield return i;
        }
    }

    public static void PrintContext(string message)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"{message}, TID={Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId}, SyncContext.Current={(SynchronizationContext.Current?.GetType().Name?.ToString() ?? "null")}");
    }
}
```

Sample output when I run the code:

```
Generating Data: 0, TID=1, SyncContext.Current=WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext
Data - item: 0, TID=1, SyncContext.Current=WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext
Generating Data: 1, TID=1, SyncContext.Current=WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext
Data - item: 1, TID=1, SyncContext.Current=WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext
Generating Data: 2, TID=1, SyncContext.Current=WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext
Data - item: 2, TID=1, SyncContext.Current=WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext
Generating Data: 3, TID=1, SyncContext.Current=WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext
Data - item: 3, TID=1, SyncContext.Current=WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext
```

Comment: I might be mistaken but I think `ConfigureAwait(false)` does not force another synchronisationcontext so it might be the same as before. You are just saying do not capture the synchronisationcontext.  That would be a reason for your observation.

Comment: Yes, I would expect the code inside the foreach loop to have no Synchronization context (ruinning on the Threadpool), but in my experiment above, the context is still there inside the loop. Added sample output in my question.

Comment: It seems that just setting ConfigAwait to false, in for each loop does not matter, but I need to set it in both. I thought they where not that "connected".

Comment: You are missunderstanding what happens on await , this might be informative for you https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

Comment: @jeb, I know about that blogpost, but that is all about async I/O operations, i am just curious about why the ConfigureAwait(false) does not "remove" the context inside the foreach loop how I would explain what ConfigureAwait(false) in the foreach loop do in my example. I am fully aware about what happens inside the GetData method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GetData` iterator captures the ambient synchronization context on each `await`, because the `await` is configured with [`ConfigureAwait(true)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait). So the continuation after the `await` runs on the captured synchronization context. Since the `GetData` is enumerated on the UI thread, the ambient synchronization context is the `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`, which is captured, so the continuation runs on the UI thread.

Your expectation that using the external [`ConfigureAwait(false)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskasyncenumerableextensions.configureawait) on the enumeration would somehow redirect the enumeration to the `ThreadPool` is not based. The `ConfigureAwait` just configures the capturing of the context. It's not a redirector/context-switcher. In case there is a context present, the `ConfigureAwait(false)` will not capture it, but the context will stay there. The `ConfigureAwait(false)` is not a context-eliminator. It's not a call to action. It's a declaration of indifference. It basically says: *"I don't care if a context exists, and I will act like it doesn't, even if it does."*

A common misconception is that in the absence of a synchronization context, the `await` continuation is running on the `ThreadPool`. In reality the continuation is running on whatever thread completed the awaited `Task`. You can find an experimental demonstration of this fact in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543240/what-thread-runs-the-code-after-the-await-keyword/77392646#77392646).

In case you want to run the enumeration on the `ThreadPool`, you can just enclose the whole enumeration in a [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run):

```
await Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await foreach (var item in data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
        DataFactory.PrintContext("Data - item: " + item);
    }
}
```

This way the `GetData` iterator will find no synchronization context to capture, making the internal `ConfigureAwait(true)` irrelevant. The enumeration will start on the `ThreadPool` (because of the `Task.Run`), and will stay on the `ThreadPool` because that's where the `Task.Delay` is completed by design. So it's coincidental. The `Task.Run` by itself doesn't guarantee that the whole enumeration will happen on the `ThreadPool`. It only affects where the enumeration starts.

Comment: How any continuations within `GetData` are scheduled should have no bearing on the continuations added within `button1_Click`.  `button1_Click` scheduled it's continuations to *not* run on the UI context, so barring the task being completed before it was awaited (which is *technically* possible, but realistically not possible outside of major debugger misuse) the continuations should be running on the default scheduler.

Comment: The expected behavior is for the "Generating Data:" lines to be on the UI context and the "Data - item: " to not be.  The two continuations both decide whether to capture the context independently.

Comment: @Servy I think that you share the same misunderstanding with the OP about what the `ConfigureAwait(false)` does. "Don't capture the context" doesn't mean "eliminate the context". It is not difficult to prove that the `ConfigureAwait(false)` doesn't cause a switch to the `ThreadPool`. I could provide an experimental proof if you would like to see one. You might find also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543240/what-thread-runs-the-code-after-the-await-keyword/77392646#77392646) informative.

Comment: @theodor Thanks for your answer. Yes, adding Task.Run would work fine of course. Just curious about how I would explain to a "junior" what ConfigureAwait(false) does inside the foreach loop. My "assumption" was that ConfigureAwait(false) is a "context" eliminator, and inside the loop, I would not have any context.