# Async method continuation runs on ThreadPool thread

Tags: c#, async-await

The below program when executed is showing that the continuation of the async methods uses a thread from the thread pool but based on my understanding for the async await, the continuation should be on the same main thread. I tried with the `ConfigureAwait` but the results did not change

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start of program");

        // Call the asynchronous method twice
        var task1 =  CallAsyncMethod();
        var task2 =  CallAsyncMethod();

        //code that needs execution
         
        await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);

        Console.WriteLine("End of program");
    }

    static async Task CallAsyncMethod()
    {
        int x = 10;
        Console.WriteLine("Start of CallAsyncMethod");

        // Simulate an already completed task with Task.FromResult
        await Task.Delay(1000);

        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        Console.WriteLine("End of CallAsyncMethod");
    }
}
```

Output

```
Start of program
Start of CallAsyncMethod
Start of CallAsyncMethod
5
End of CallAsyncMethod
11
End of CallAsyncMethod
End of program
```

While I was expecting the output to be

```
Start of program
Start of CallAsyncMethod
Start of CallAsyncMethod
1
End of CallAsyncMethod
1
End of CallAsyncMethod
End of program
```

Comment: You are calling a TASK and the Task will have a different ID from the main function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52686862/why-the-default-synchronizationcontext-is-not-captured-in-a-console-app

Comment: Console apps don't have a Synchronisation Context. See also https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/

Comment: Related: [What thread runs the code after the `await` keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543240/what-thread-runs-the-code-after-the-await-keyword)

Comment: @KlausGütter Adding... but you can give the main thread a SynchronizationContext by putting the `[STAThread]` attribute on your `Main` function.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I will go through the provided answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the continuation of the async methods uses a thread from the thread pool but based on my understanding for the async await, the continuation should be on the same main thread.

Your current understanding of `await` is incorrect. I explain the semantics [on my blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

By default, `await` captures a context, and this context is used to execute the continuation. This "context" is the current `SynchronizationContext`, unless there isn't one, in which case it is the current `TaskScheduler`. If you override the default behavior with `ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false)`, or if there isn't a context (as in this case, in a Console application), then no context is captured.

When no context is captured, the continuation just runs on whatever thread completes the task, which is a thread pool thread the vast majority of the time.

Comment: Many Thanks @Stephen Cleary. It would be good if you refer to the blog you mentioned above in the "There is no thread blog" https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html OR if you mention that at the end of the blog not just in the comments.