# Why is there a different behavior on async-await usage?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

In the first program, as you can see, the beginner thread `1` starts execution. In the middle or somewhere, while printing dots, another thread having the name `10` comes into play. When it completes its relationship with `FetchAndShowHeaders` method, it passes away. Then, the beginner thread `1` goes its way until the `Main` method(there is no need to write the Main method explicitly).

In the second program, as you can see, the beginner thread `5` starts execution. While waiting for the complement of `FetchAndShowHeaders`, 121(11*11) dots are written on the console by the beginner thread `5` and another thread `9` comes into play for the result in `FetchAndShowHeaders` method and its continuation. **The important part** begins. Unlike the first program, in the second program, the thread used for the `FetchAndShowHeaders` method continues execution of `Main()` instead of the beginner thread `5`.

It is confusing for me. Could you please detail and teach me?

The first program,

```
Console.WriteLine("print1 Thread Name = {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
Task q = FetchAndShowHeaders("http://www.fultonbank.com");
Console.WriteLine("print2 Thread Name = {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
for (int i = 0; i < 500_000_0; i++)
{
    for (int ii = 0; ii < 500; ii++)
    {
        if (i % 500_000 == 0)
            Console.Write(".");
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("\nprint5 Thread Name = {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
await q;
Console.WriteLine("print6 Thread Name = {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
return;

async Task FetchAndShowHeaders(string url)
{
    using var w = new HttpClient();
    var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Head, url);
    Console.WriteLine("\nprint3_method_inside Thread Name = {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    var response = await w.SendAsync(req, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
    Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(
        response.Headers.ToString()));
        Console.WriteLine("\nprint4_method_inside Thread Name = {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
}

//Output:
/*
print1 Thread Name = 1

print3_method_inside Thread Name = 1
print2 Thread Name = 1
......................................
................................."Date: Sat, 10
 Feb 2024 21:08:01 GMT\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nSet-Cookie: 
AWSALB=yoEkz4GX4D6NZxccaPs1OQfQGu0yNRocZplmI6TE1pU1GB2BNwAcQ01\u002Bc; Expires=Sat,
 17 Feb 2024 21:08:01 GMT; Path=/, AWSALBCORS=yoEkz4GX4D6NZIci84X7t\u
 002BNwAcQ01\u002Bc; Expires=Sat, 17 Feb 2024 21:08:01 GMT; Path=/; 
 SameSite=None; Secure, ASP.NET_SessionId=al3ekazz02q0up1oja4i0ify; 
 path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax,\r\nX-Frame-Options: 
 DENY\r\nStrict-Transport-Security: 
 max-age=31536000;includeSubDomains\r\nX-Content-Type-Options: 
 nosniff\r\nX-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block\r\n"

print4_method_inside Thread Name = 10
.................................................................
............................................................................
print5 Thread Name = 1
print6 Thread Name = 1
*/
```

The second program,

```
Console.WriteLine("print1 Thread Name = {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
Task q = FetchAndShowHeaders("http://www.fultonbank.com");
Console.WriteLine("print2 Thread Name = {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
{
    for (int ii = 0; ii < 11; ii++)
    {
        Console.Write(".");
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("\nprint5 Thread Name = {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
await q;
Console.WriteLine("print6 Thread Name = {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
return;

async Task FetchAndShowHeaders(string url)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nprint3_method_inside Thread Name = {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("\nprint4_method_inside Thread Name = {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
}

//Output:
/*
print1 Thread Name = 5

print3_method_inside Thread Name = 5
print2 Thread Name = 5
.........................................................................................................................
print5 Thread Name = 5

print4_method_inside Thread Name = 9
print6 Thread Name = 9
*/
```

Comment: Tasks are not Threads. Every time you `await` something, the Task will release it's Thread so that another part of your application can pick the Thread up and use it. When the `await` is ready (i.e. your http response comes back), the Task will then continue running on another random Thread until your next `await`. You can have (a bit) more control over this with `Task.ConfigureAwait`, but generally if you need threads, you should use `Thread` or `ThreadPool` instead of `Task`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130194/what-is-the-difference-between-task-and-thread

Comment: It seems that you want to understand [what thread runs the code after the `await` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543240/what-thread-runs-the-code-after-the-await-keyword). Short answer, in the absence of a `SynchronizationContext` you have no control of the continuation thread. It's an implementation detail of the asynchronous method.

Comment: @Shane it's true that tasks and threads are different things, but I can't see where the OP claimed that they are the same. Before trying to clear a misconception, it's a good idea to ensure that a misconception exists in the first place, otherwise [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77974806/why-is-there-a-different-behavior-on-async-await-usage#comment137465668_77974806) might be perceived as condescending.

Comment: @Shane did I mention using threads or thread creation or something similar except that continuation?

Comment: @Hax, the point I am trying to make is, if you want to control specific Threads, you will need to use Threads. If you want to execute a unit of IO work in a Thread efficient manner, you can use Tasks. There is an exception for `Task.ConfigureAwait`. To directly answer the question in your title: the "why" in this case does not matter. You are attempting to control something that Tasks purposely abstract away from you

Comment: @Shane thank you, then you should have written _the direct answer_ because that's what I wonder.

Answer (score -3):

Despite common misconceptions, tasks have nothing to do with threads.

In fact, a properly written program would show the same thread ID for your second example throughout its execution. The reason why it's not is because you never set up a [`SynchronizationContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext?view=net-8.0), and since `Task.Delay` returns a `Task` that's signaled from an external timer thread and since your `await` couldn't capture its current context, it just continues execution on that thread instead.

Comment: @Hax You are unnecessarily condescending. Somebody wastes his time to help and that's how shou show gratitude? I mean you should be grateful and not arrogant. Just say that the answer doesn't help and is based on misconception. It's not that difficult.

Comment: @Hax In your question you are clearly talking about threads and not tasks. If you don't mean threads then don't use the term. Sometimes precision is useful.

Comment: @BionicCode where did I write as such? I know better than you threads