# Sync over Async C#

Tags: c#, async-await, azure-web-app-service

I am running our Mobile backend in Azure WebApp and today I got this error message from our memory dumps as our app latency increased.

And it suggest to use await in our calls. But we already using Await in our code, below is the code form that specific endpoint.

> Api.Controllers.v5.CampaignsController.Campaigns(string, string) is waiting on System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim.Wait(int, System.Threading.CancellationToken)

Code

```
public async Task<ActionResult<BaseResponse>> Campaigns([Required] string matasID, string type = "Campaign")
    {
        _logger.Information(IntegrationLogger.GetLogMessage(_correlationId, HttpStatusCode.OK,
                                     GetType().Name, IntegrationLogger.GetActualAsyncMethodName(),
                                     $"API Call received with matas Id {matasID} to get compaigns", null));
        if (type == "Campaign")
        {
            var cacheCampaigns = await _memberCacheService.GetCampaigns(matasID);
            BaseResponse response;
            if (cacheCampaigns == null)
            {
                var campaignsResponse = await _clientv5.GetAsync<CampaignsResponseModel>($"/campaigns?type={type}");

                var filteredCampaigns = campaignsResponse.campaigns.Where(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.link)).ToList();
                campaignsResponse.campaigns = filteredCampaigns; 

                _memberCacheService.SaveCampaigns(campaignsResponse, matasID);
                response = await _memberCacheService.GetCampaigns(matasID);
            }
            else
            {
                response = cacheCampaigns;
            }
            return Ok(response);
        }             
        else
        {
            var responseModel = new FailureResponseModel
            {
                result = false,
                timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"),
                resultDetails = $"Please pass the correct parameters",
                errors = new List<Error>
                {
                    new Error{
                    description=$"The specified Type '{type}' is not valid",
                    code= 400,
                    resolve = "Please provide correct parameters"
                    }
                }
            };
            return BadRequest(responseModel);
        }
    }
```

and

```
public async Task<CampaignsResponseModel> GetCampaigns(string matasID)
    {
        try
        {
            _logger.Information(IntegrationLogger.GetLogMessage(_correlationId, HttpStatusCode.OK,
                                     GetType().Name, IntegrationLogger.GetActualAsyncMethodName(),
                                     $"Getting compaigns for User {matasID}", null));

            var cacheCampaigns = await _redisClient.Db3.GetAsync<CampaignsResponseModel>(matasID);

            return cacheCampaigns;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(IntegrationLogger.GetLogMessage(_correlationId, HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
                                    GetType().Name, IntegrationLogger.GetActualAsyncMethodName(),
                                    $"Getting compaigns for User {matasID} Failed", ex.Message));
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Another Warning

> Api.Controllers.v5.MembersController.GetSpecificMemberInfo(string) is waiting on System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim.Wait(int, System.Threading.CancellationToken)

```
 _logger.Information(IntegrationLogger.GetLogMessage(_correlationId, HttpStatusCode.OK,
                                                 GetType().Name, IntegrationLogger.GetActualAsyncMethodName(),
                                                 $"API call received to get specific member info with the matas Id {matasID}", null));
    
        MemberShortResponseModel response = await _memberInfoService.GetShortInfo(matasID);
        response.acceptedPermissionVersion = response.termsAcceptVersion;
        Shop shop = null;

        if (response.shopId != null)
        {
            shop = await _shopCacheService.GetShopByShopId(response.shopId).ConfigureAwait(true);
        }

        response.shop = shop;
        return Ok(response);
```

and this is code for GetShopByID, here we are again using await

```
public async Task<Shop> GetShopByShopId(string shopId)
    {
        _logger.Information(IntegrationLogger.GetLogMessage(_correlationId, HttpStatusCode.OK,
                                     GetType().Name, IntegrationLogger.GetActualAsyncMethodName(),
                                     $"Fetching Shop By shopId", null));

        var cacheShop = await _redisClient.Db1.GetAsync<Shop>(shopId);

        return cacheShop;
    }
```

[image]
Can someone help me understanding the issue here.

Comment: how GetShopByShopId is related to `GetSpecificMemberInfo` and error message you post?

Comment: Well GetShopByShopID is being called from GetSpecificMemberInfo, that's why I shared the full flow code.

Comment: Check redis health?  Is redis in the same location as the app?

Comment: I think, you should provide related code in GetSpecificMemberInfo. As well as full error message and stack trace

Comment: Yes, redis is same location as app, also it was available at that time.

Comment: `ConfigureAwait(true)` is the default behavior. Why is that call there? Did you intend to write `ConfigureAwait(false)` instead?

Comment: In your Title you mention 'sync' but I don't see the _sync_ bit in your code. Are you doing something in `_memberCacheService.GetCampaigns()` that is trying to be synchronous that should use `await`? (also check `GetShopByShopId()`)

Comment: I provided GetCampaigns() Code as well.

Comment: It's complaining about using `SemaphoreSlim.Wait`, wanting you to use `await SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync` instead. If none of your code uses `SemaphoreSlim`, it may be one of the libraries you're using. Toggle "Just my code" off and examine the full stack trace.

Comment: I did tried doing that, but I don't understand what's happening in the stack trace.

Answer (score -1):

This is generally caused by

```
.ConfigureAwait(true);
```

Unless you have some specific locking requirements that are not listed in the post, you would not normally use this in the context of an API.

- Can you explain why you want to sychronize the callback thread?

For this to work you would need to configure a synchronization context manually because there is no UI thread automatically configured for APIs. But that is because we do not need one. It is more common to use `false` in API scenarios if the same code might be executed from a UI context based application like Win Forms or WPF.

For API development, in modern runtimes, it is safer to not specify `ConfigureAwait()` at all. There is older guidance for .Net FX and .Net Standard that say you should *always* `ConfigureAwait()` but the default implementations have been fixed in modern code to reduce the redundancy in the code itself.

This is explored in this post: [When should I use ConfigureAwait(true)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56924778/1690217)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. But in memory dump i have another stack trace as well, with similar warning. I have updated my question as well, and provide relevant code and stacktrace as well.

Comment: Did you try removing `.ConfigureAwait(true);` and re-executing?

Comment: Yes will remove that and deploy again to see how it works. But can you check my updated question as well.