# Is there a timing/race condition with my C# code?

Tags: c#, .net, handler

I'm trying to test that my custom IProgress is doing what I expect it to do: "Report" the current status after every second.

So I have some code but it's always failing. But this is the kicker - it's only failing when I have *hardly any code in the test case*.

If I add in one more piece of code to the test (which is commented out in the repo) .. it works if I uncomment that.

It's like .. something needs to get fired off .. but it hasn't completed before the "assertions" are checked.

Full fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qXHzlx

Here's the code:

```
// Arrange.
var reportValue = 0;
var progress = new TimerProgress<int>((int value) => reportValue = value);

await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)); // Need to wait more than 1 second for the report to work.

// Act.
progress.Report(5);

// Assert.
reportValue.ShouldBe(5);
```

and the custom `TimerProgress` :

```
public class TimerProgress<T> : IProgress<T>
{
    private readonly TimeSpan _intervalInMilliseconds;
    private readonly IProgress<T> _progress;
    private DateTime? _lastReportedOn;

    public TimerProgress(Action<T> handler, double intervalInMillieconds = 1000)
    {
        if (intervalInMillieconds <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(intervalInMillieconds));
        }

        _intervalInMilliseconds = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(intervalInMillieconds);

        _progress = new Progress<T>(handler);

        _lastReportedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

    public void Report(T value)
    {
        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

        if (now - _lastReportedOn > _intervalInMilliseconds)
        {
            // We're due for a report!
            _progress.Report(value);
        }

        _lastReportedOn = now;
    }
}
```

With the test case, I expect:

- new `TimeProgress` instance. `Now` is "remembered".
- Wait 2 seconds (you'll see why in a tick)
- "Report". This now checks to see if `remembered-now` is over 1 second ago. It *should be* because we've waited for 2 seconds! So now, we should "report"
- Handler gets called .. which 'remembers' the number 5
- we now assert that '5' was ended up getting reported.

So I keep getting a failure assertion saying the value is `0`, not `5`.

But when I add one more line of code to the test, then the value is now `5`.

Is this about a timing or event firing issue?

Is this about how my handler is trying to update a variable *outside* of the handler, which is Bad™️ ?

### Edit

Suggestions from people are saying that the `Progress<T>` [actually uses a sync context under the hood](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Progress.cs,75) and this is the issue?

Comment: It wasn't me but you've not included any code and while having the fiddle is good, we don't necessarily want to click another link. Just paste your code in the question.

Comment: It appears to be related to the use of `Progress<T>`. If you call the delegate `handler` directly, it immediately sets it.

Comment: Your reporting is not done asynchronously.  It is done after the 2 second wait.  A real asynchronous application the report would be sent during the 2 second wait.

Comment: Updated OP with more info/data/research

Comment: The handler is called and the variable is updated, but it's called after `reportValue.ShouldBe(5);` is evaluated. The docs for `Progress` say: "*If there is no current SynchronizationContext at the time of construction, the callbacks will be invoked on the ThreadPool.*" I'm guessing this means `.Report` schedules it for execution in another thread, and that it returns without waiting for it to happen.

Comment: Yep - that's what i'm thinking, also @ikegami . it's it's not easy?? to define my own context?

Answer (score -1):

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41239945/is-it-possible-to-control-the-synchronizationcontext-used-by-a-net-progresst) has a great conversation about this issue, already.

It is because the progress runs on a `SynchronizationContext`. So they suggested not to use the `Progress<T>` inside my own class. Instead, just call the `Action<T>` *directly* which means it will happen in your current context.

e.g. (stolen code)

```
public class SynchronousProgress<T> : IProgress<T>
{
    private readonly Action<T> action;

    public SynchronousProgress(Action<T> action)
    {
        this.action = action;
    }

    public void Report(T value)
    {
        action(value);
    }
}
```